# The Formik handleSubmit function appears to be non-functional when attempting to initiate the submission process by clicking the submit button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

In this component, I created a form using Formik a few days ago, and it was functioning correctly. However, today I noticed that it is no longer operational. Upon investigation, I discovered that the handleFormSubmit function is not being triggered when the submit button is clicked. Here's the code for the component:

```
const UpdateUser = ({ user, open, handleClose }) => {

   const isNonMobile = useMediaQuery("(min-width:600px)");

   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState(initialState);

   const { loading, error, userCreated } = useUser();

   // fetch the selected user's data   
   useEffect(() => {
      const formattedResponse = {
         ...user,
         birthday: dateFormat(user?.birthday),
         contractStartDate: dateFormat(user?.contractStartDate),
         contractEndDate: dateFormat(user?.contractEndDate),
      };
      setInitialValues(formattedResponse);
   }, [user]);

   const handleFormSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {

      console.log("asslema");
      const dataForRequest = {
         ...values,
         "roles": [ROLE_FOR_POSTE[values.jobTitle]],
      };
      try {
         dispatch(userUpdate(dataForRequest, user.id));
         console.log("besslema");
         setSubmitting(false);
      } catch (error) {
         console.error("Error:", error);
         setSubmitting(false);
      }

   };

   return (
      <Dialog maxWidth='md' fullWidth open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
         <DialogTitle>
            <Header title="Modification" subtitle="Effectuer les ajustements requis pour cet utilisateur." />
         </DialogTitle>
         <DialogContent>
            {
               userCreated || error ?
                  <Alert
                     severity={error ? "error" : "success"}
                     action={
                        <Button size="sm" variant="solid" color="inherit" onClick={handleClose}>
                           Close
                        </Button>
                     }
                  >
                     {
                        !error ?
                           "La mise à jour de l'utilisateur a été effectuée avec succès."
                           :
                           "La mise à jour de l'utilisateur a échoué."
                     }
                  </Alert>
                  :
                  loading ?
                     <Box sx={{ height: '400px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <CircularProgress color='success' size={100} />
                     </Box>
                     :
                     <Box m="20px">
                        <Formik
                           onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
                           initialValues={initialValues}
                           validationSchema={userSchema}
                        >
                           {({
                              values,
                              errors,
                              touched,
                              handleBlur,
                              handleChange,
                              handleSubmit,
                           }) => (
                              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                 <Box
                                    display="grid"
                                    gap="30px"
                                    gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))"
                                    sx={{
                                       "& > div": { gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : "span 4" },
                                    }}
                                 >
                                    <TextField
                                       fullWidth
                                       variant="filled"
                                       type="text"
                                       label="Nom"
                                       onBlur={handleBlur}
                                       onChange={handleChange}
                                       value={values.firstName}
                                       name="firstName"
                                       error={!!touched.firstName && !!errors.firstName}
                                       helperText={touched.firstName && errors.firstName}
                                       sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                    />
                                    <TextField
                                       fullWidth
                                       variant="filled"
                                       type="text"
                                       label="Prénom"
                                       onBlur={handleBlur}
                                       onChange={handleChange}
                                       value={values.lastName}
                                       name="lastName"
                                       error={!!touched.lastName && !!errors.lastName}
                                       helperText={touched.lastName && errors.lastName}
                                       sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                    />
                                    <TextField
                                       fullWidth
                                       variant="filled"
                                       type="number"
                                       label="Téléphone"
                                       onBlur={handleBlur}
                                       onChange={handleChange}
                                       value={values.phone}
                                       name="phone"
                                       error={!!touched.phone && !!errors.phone}
                                       helperText={touched.phone && errors.phone}
                                       sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                    />
....others input fields
                                 </Box>
                                 <Box mt="30px" display="flex" gap="10px" justifyContent="flex-end">
                                    <Button color="error" variant="outlined" onClick={handleClose}>Annuler</Button>
//this is the submit button
                                    <Button color="success" variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Enregistrer</Button>
                                 </Box>
                              </form>
                           )}
                        </Formik>
                     </Box>
            }
         </DialogContent>
      </Dialog >
   );
};
```

what's wrong here ?

correct the issue within the Formik form.

Comment: Try By removing the onClick from the "Enregistrer" (Submit) button, the form submission should work as expected when you click the button. The handleSubmit function provided by Formik will be called, and it will trigger your handleFormSubmit function, which performs the necessary form submission logic.

Comment: @ChaudhariDevam , I've followed those steps, but the issue persists.